# Implement a delay on $scope.$watch

Tags: angularjs

I was wondering whether or not it is possible to implement a slight delay on $scope.$watch. I have the following which queries the server, so I'd like to implement a slight delay before it evaluates the `query` before querying the server. I've noticed that if you type to quickly it gets confused and doesn't send the correct information:

```
$scope.$watch("query", function () {
    $scope.loading = true;
    returnFactory.query($scope.query).then(function (returns) {
        $scope.returns = returns;
        $scope.loading = false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Normally i'd say use angular's $timeout for this delay but you cant clear this timeout yet.

**//EDIT**:you can.

Set a timeout and clear it, if this watcher gets triggered fast enought.

Like this:

```
var timeoutCode;
var delayInMs = 2000;
$scope.$watch("query", function(query) {
 clearTimeout(timeoutCode);  //does nothing, if timeout alrdy done
 timeoutCode = setTimeout(function(){   //Set timeout
     $scope.loading = true;
     returnFactory.query(query).then(function(returns) {
       $scope.returns = returns;
       $scope.loading = false;
     });
 },delayInMs);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4FuyY/

**UPDATE** Thanks to stewie
this can be achieved with angular's $timeout.

```
    var timeoutPromise;
    var delayInMs = 2000;
    $scope.$watch("query", function(query) {
     $timeout.cancel(timeoutPromise);  //does nothing, if timeout alrdy done
     timeoutPromise = $timeout(function(){   //Set timeout
         $scope.loading = true;
         returnFactory.query(query).then(function (returns) {
           $scope.returns = returns;
           $scope.loading = false;
         });
     },delayInMs);
    });
```

Comment: there's a button on the editor to tab the code out. No need for `<code>` tags. Just select, press the button to add a tab. Bam done :)

Comment: `$timeout` **can** be cleared with `$timeout.cancel(timeoutPromise)`.

Comment: @Phill: I got this now, thanks !
To Stewie: good point, i didn't find any api docs about this?

Comment: If you wanted manually code a debounce this is one way to do it.  Better is to simply use the debounce built into ng-model-options like the solution below.

Answer (score 13):

you can use ng-model-option, if the model 'query' is a Html tag or Angular directive, for Ej:

```
<input type ng-model="query" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: { 'default':
 2000, 'blur': 1 } }" />
```

You can see the Angular Doc here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

Comment: The timeout method above causes some weird page refreshes. This code worked as expected. I had a field in a Data Table, and just adding the `{ debounce: 500 }` allowed them to enter digits without the table refreshing in the middle of their work. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I like to use [Lo-Dash](http://lodash.com/) which provides two really useful capabilities: [debounce](http://lodash.com/docs#debounce) and [throttle](http://lodash.com/docs#throttle) which does exactly what you want.  Let's say you want to make sure it only calls the function once per 150 ms:

```
function update() {
 $scope.loading = true;
    returnFactory.query($scope.query).then(function (returns) {
        $scope.returns = returns;
        $scope.loading = false;
    });
}

$scope.$watch("query", function () {
   _.throttle(update, 150);
});
```

The `throttle` function lets you control when the `update` function is called (trailing or leading edge).

I use Lo-Dash all the time in my app.  It is a must-have library for me... more useful than jQuery.  But, you can create a custom build of Lo-Dash which only includes the `throttle` and `debounce` functions if you don't want to include the entire library.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Hadn't heard of Lo-Dash before! Thanks for the link!

Comment: No problem.  Think of Lo-Dash as a fork of Underscore.  All the capabilities of Underscore (plus more) and it is more performant.

Comment: Lodash is great and a must for any project, but worth noting that using `debounce` from lodash prevents unit testing. If you need unit testing, you may want to consider a debounce implementation based on `$timeout`, because angular-mocks provides `$timeout.flush()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the current value of `query` to decide when you want to fire the call:

```
$scope.$watch("query", function (value) {

    //implement rule here for value
    //example value is at least 3 characters
    if (value && value.length > 3) {

        $scope.loading = true;
        returnFactory.query($scope.query).then(function (returns) {
            $scope.returns = returns;
            $scope.loading = false;
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a snippet that I found useful for similar case:

```
function watchWithDelay(scope, prop, callback, delayMs) {
  delayMs = delayMs || 1000;
  var lastTimeChanged = new Date();
  scope.$watch(prop, function(n, o) {
    lastTimeChanged = new Date();
    setTimeout(function() {
      var diff = new Date().getTime() - lastTimeChanged.getTime();
      if (diff < delayMs-100 || diff > delayMs+100) {
        return;
      }
      callback(n, o);
    }, delayMs);
  });
}
```

You can use it in a controller like this:

```
watchWithDelay($scope, 'client.phone', function(n, o) {
  if (n === o) {
    return;
  }
  // any custom validations, for example
  if (!n) {
    return alert('Phone is required');
  }
  if (n.length < 11) {
    return alert('Phone is shorter than 11 digits');
  }
  // here I should save it somehow
  console.log('Phone is changed to ' + n);
});
```