# How to use different ngModelOptions based on the ngModel's validity

Tags: angularjs, validation, user-experience, angular-ngmodel

I'm currently using `ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: { default: 500, blur: 0 } }"` in order to try to avoid showing errors to my users while they're in the middle of filling out an input. However, I find it jarring that this also makes the errors, once they've appeared, stay longer even if the error has already been corrected.

I was wondering if there was some (non-hacky) way of dynamically changing the ngModelOptions based on the ngModel's validity, so that if the model's valid it will only validate changes on blur, while if it's invalid it will validate immediately. The end result of this would be that errors disappear as fast as possible, while they don't appear again until absolutely necessary.

Comment: You could use a watcher ($scope.$watch) to do so, applying the debounce within the watch method using $timeout (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20397253/implement-a-delay-on-scope-watch). This way, you can apply the debounce only if needed

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking of the same and the only way I could think of is to:
Set the default debounce to 0 too and then watch whether field is invalid/valid. 
Inside that watch:

- delay showing error if the field is invalid with $timeout
- but to remove the error immediately once the field is valid (don't forget also to remove the $timeout).